# index.html throwing an error in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I am following along with [this Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/javascript-advanced/) on "Advanced JavaScript", currently reviewing Scopes and watching the video "
9. What is an IIFE and why might you use it?".

The instructor is using Chrome DevTools to show JS examples, and created the following three snippets - [main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cydWe.png), [other.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFdfj.png), [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXFgK.png)

The instructor is trying to show that running main.js will print out:

`main: Object{hello: "main"}`

`other: Object{hello: "other"}`

For some reason my index.html file that I'm creating in Chrome DevTools has an error (x) on line 1. I have it saved as "index.html" and following along exactly, so not sure why the doc isn't being recognized as html. I tried refreshing and saving but nothing.

[my index.html with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2GX0.png)

Semi-related, I tried to run main.js with other.js and index.html written out and saved, but main.js only prints out < main >{hello: "main"} >, not the other.js object as well. I assume this has to be due to the index.html file not working properly.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I really cannot find a syntax error in your code, maybe there is another factor affecting your results.

Comment: What if you remove the `<script>` tags? Do you still get that error indicator in line 1 of `index.html`?

Comment: I removed the <script> tags, both the tags and the lines entirely. Still had the same error each time - Unexpected token '<' on line 1.

Comment: I believe somebody was able to answer by question on Reddit. Posting his answer here...

"Looks like you are using snippets, which is used to write javascript code. Even though you have .js and .html extensions chrome still sees it as a js file. The instructor is probably using workspaces"