# Old mapping showing up with Workspaces. How can I establish a new mapping and/or close out a previously used port?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, port, workspace

So this is a follow up question to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121329/index-html-throwing-an-error-in-chrome-devtools) I had regarding a [Udemy course on "Advanced Javascript](https://www.udemy.com/course/javascript-advanced/) I am taking. I am currently trying to follow along with a lesson on IIFE.

The instructor is using Chrome DevTools to show JS examples, and created the following three snippets - [main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cydWe.png), [other.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFdfj.png), [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXFgK.png).

As per an earlier question I had answered, it appears that the instructor is using Workspaces to map files from a local directory to work on them in Chrome DevTools (otherwise the index.html wouldn't function in DevTools just using snippets)

So... I paused the Udemy course to complete this short [Workspaces demo](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces). After completing the demo, I went back to the Udemy course, created a local directory with the main.js, other.js, and index.html files and tried to follow the instructions per the Workspaces demo for my Udemy files.

However, after running  in my js-advanced/IIFE directory and navigating to localhost:8000 in Chrome, [I still see the old index.html from the Workspaces demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1xG7.png). Even after navigating to Sources > Filesystem and opening up the new folder, I can't get the page to map to my new directory.

I am assuming that there's something I'm missing regarding ports being opened and not closed after following the tutorial. But maybe not. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm technically using Brave Browser but it's built on top of Chrome so I don't think that should matter.

Comment: you do not have to create workspaces in chorme to make your IFFE ( Or any javascript code ) work. Make it simple, just reference your javascript file using the regular script tag in your html, double click on it and it will work.

Comment: I understand that what I'm doing isn't necessary the most efficient, but I'm not trying to write a full program at the moment. I'm just trying to follow along with the Udemy tutorial that is using Workspaces, and now have a secondary question that has risen regarding the use of Workspaces. So let's say I did want to use workspaces to view my main.js/other.js/index.html files in my IIFE directory.. how do I get them to map in DevTools workspaces and replace the stupid "I <3 Cake" index.html file that was set up on locaport:8000 from the Workspaces tutorial? Sorry if I am not articulating well.